# Optimize loading time in MySQL Database

Tags: mysql, etl, talend

I have a huge amount of data which is loaded from ETL tool into the database. Sometimes etl tool generates some unusual data and puts them inside a table, say for simlicity I want to fill 5 correct data and get 10 as a result in my database, so I detect the inconsistency.

As the option to update data to the state which I want I had to TRUNCATE the schema in MySQL database and INSERT data from ETL tool again under my control. In this case everything looks nice, but it takes too much time to reload data.

I investigated this issue and found out that to DELETE data and INSERT it again takes much more time as for example to use the query INSERT…..ON DUPLICATE KEY UPDATE. So I don‘t need to delete all data but can just check and update it when necessary, what will save my load time.

I want to use this query, but I am a little bit confused, because of these additional 5 wrong data, which are already sitting in my database. How can I remove them without deleting everything from my table before inserting??

Comment: can you show data

Comment: unfortunately I cannot show data here, but I can say its size, its around 8GB

Comment: so their some unique key for hat data by which you can use delete condition on that data

Comment: I thought about writing a query that deletes data, which was not affected with my previous INSERT…..ON DUPLICATE KEY UPDATE query, but I am not sure yet if it is possible with SQL, need to check it as well.

Comment: you have to make a coloum a unique key so it's stop duplicate

Comment: no, they don't have a unique key

Comment: its actually thought to be the rows not unique by the system we use and I can't  change it. Therefore I am looking for solution that will not change the table but will change the approach to manipulate data more effectively.

Comment: I'm a little bit confused about your unique-index-comment: you can add a unique index for the rows that define a column as a duplicate, worst case you add all columns to that index. If there are no columns that make your rows unique, then how would any algorithm (or you) decide if they are already in the database? Or is there something else that defines "wrong data"?

Comment: Yes, you are right, I replied confusing indeed, sorry for that. I've meant that the Id key is not unique in a schema, but of course there is one column in a table, which makes the rows unique. But how can this help me in my problem, if for example the wrong data has its own unique key which is different to the correct data? How I can remove it from database?

Comment: @Eric how does your data look like? Provide some sample data which has duplicate.

Answer (score 0):

as you mention

> "Sometimes etl tool generates some unusual data and puts them inside
>   a table"

You need to investigate your ETL code and correct it. Its not suppose to generate any data, ETL tool only transforms your data as per rule. Focus on ETL code rather than MySQL database.

Answer (score 0):

To me that sounds like there’s a problem in the dataflow setup in your ETL tool.  You don’t say what you are using, but I would go back over the select criteria and review what fields you are selecting and what are your WHERE criteria.  Perhaps what is in your WHERE statements is causing the extra data.

As for the INSERT…ON DUPLICATE KEY UPDATE syntax, make sure you don’t have an AUTO_INCREMENT column in an InnoDB table.  Because in that case only the INSERT will increase the auto-increment value.  And check that your table doesn’t have multiple unique indexes because if your WHERE a=xx matches several rows than only 1 will be updated.  (MySQL 5.7, see reference manual:  https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/ .)

If you find that your ETL tools are not providing enough flexibility then you could investigate other options.  Here is a good article [comparing ETL tools](http://blog.panoply.io/11-great-etl-tools-and-the-case-for-saying-no-to-etl).